Baking a 6" cheesecake inside 10" silicone pan in water bath?
I don't have time to buy a smaller silicone pan.  Will 2" gap around cheesecake pan make a difference while baking in a water bath?

I’m struggling to understand the setup. Can you explain in more detail, what exactly you are trying to do and what kind and size of pans you have?

@Stephie it sounds like OP is trying to make cheesecake in a 6" pan, placed inside a 10" pan with water for bain-marie. Does it make any difference to use a 6" pan instead of a smaller size?
